# SQL Server : Get position (ordinal) of a record in a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I have a table that stores a queue of tasks. Every task looks like:

```
Id | Operation | Argument | Status
```

Operation is a string
Argument is a single number
Status is one of : `Queued`, `Busy`, `Complete`, `Failed`

I need to figure out a position of an item in a queue, but need to skip tasks that are not queued.

Example:

```
1 A 5 Queued   -- 1
2 A 6 Queued   -- 2
3 B 3 Busy     -- x
4 B 4 Complete -- x
5 A 8 Queued   -- 3
```

Expected position follows `--` position `x` means request is meaningless.

**Question:** what would be a good way to calculate such position?
At the moment I do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.Position FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Status, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Id) as Position 
    from QueuedJobs where Status = 0 AND Id <= @taskId
) as p
order by Position desc
```

In English: Calculate positions of each task up to my task, and give me the last position (which is my task)

My concern is performance, let's say I have 1000 records and have many requests (100's every second).
Database is SQL Server 2008

Comment: The query is correct and should perform OK. "concern is performance": is it actually slow or are you thinking that it will be slow (IOW, have you tested its slowness)?

Comment: @smirkingman: I am doing premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query without an order by clause can return the rows in any order. What criterion is used to order the  queued requests that are not busy or completed?  Is it a FIFO queue? The oldest request is at the top? Typically a datetime value is used for that purpose. In any case, I'd number the rows in the order returned by the query in the front-end, where it would be done much more efficiently.

Comment: Yes, it is a FIFO. Won't `over (order by Id)` ensure that row_number is returned for rows **ordered* by Id?  The whole point of this piece is to show the user the position their task is at in the queue. I don't think pulling 1000 records over the wire just to determine the position of a row is a good idea - could you elaborate on that please.

Comment: @user93422: It is not considered robust design to attribute any meaning to the ID (e.g. position in queue, temporal sequence, etc). An ID is simply there to differentiate the row from all others (i.e. to be a unique handle to the row). Why not robust? What if you should need to "bump" a task up in the queue, give it higher priority? You cannot change the ID (PK) value. To indicate queue position I'd probably use a Float or a DateTime.

Comment: That is, I'd add a Float or DateTime column to the row.

Answer (score 0):

If Status 0 means "Queued", then:

```
Select Count(*)
From QueuedJobs
Where Status = 0
  and Id <= @taskId
```

Should tell you where you are :)

Comment: Bad practice to rely on primary key to convey any sort of meaning.

Comment: Tim. The predicate is from the poster's query; he orders by Id descending and collects the value of the last one, no? I don't think I added meaning to any already implied.

Comment: @Lynnette: your practice or his, it's not generally a good idea to rely upon the ID for anything other than a unique handle.